# (NVIDIA Jetson TX2 ) SDK Manager can’t detect Target Hardware “no board connected”

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, ubuntu-sdk

I’m using virtualbox of ubuntu 18.04 flashing Jetson TX2 by SDK Manager

**problem: my virtualbox of ubuntu 18.04 can’t detact target Hardware Jetson TX2, but local pc with Ubuntu 20.04 could, I want virtualbox ubuntu 18.04 detact too**

---

virtualbox of ubuntu 18.04: cannot sense the target Hardware Jetson TX2

[image]

---

local pc with Ubuntu 20.04: can sense the target Hardware Jetson TX2
[image]

Comment: Vms don't have access to the real hardware, only to the virtualized hardware presented to the OS by the virtualization software (Virtualbox in this case). Some USB devices can be easily passed to the VM (and disconnection from the host). Have you used the USB passtrough feature, assuming the device is USB connected?

Answer (score 0):

as @ChanganAuto said using the `used the USB passthrough feature` can solve it

the result pic: by adding/connecting usb port to the virtualbox system, now SDK manager can detect Target hardware Tx2
[image: the result pic: by adding/connecting usb port to the virtualbox system, now SDK manager can detect Target hardware Tx2]

I follow this video:(for linux) https://youtu.be/zdZLFeLXa14